# Signing and encryption formats/specs for Windows PPKG provisioning files

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, signing

I am researching a possible project for building provisioning package files (.ppkg) files as created by the Windows Configuration Designer (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-packages) for context). My goal is to build a C# assembly I can integrate into an existing application. I have already found documentation and code bases from which I have coded a working proof-of-concept that will create an unencrypted and unsigned .ppkg file. The only missing pieces are signing and encryption (which are existing features of the Windows Configuration Designer). I am looking for information on the algorithms and data formats applied by the Configuration Designer when it signs and/or encrypts a package, so that I can replicate these features in my assembly.

Comment: If I understand, correctly you want to emulate this functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-create-packagecin your own code? What platform is this?

Comment: Or you mean you're looking for the private keys needed to provision your own DeviceContextAppLicense?

Comment: @8vtwo I have built a library which can create a ppkg file as is generated from this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/windows-configuration-designer/9nblggh4tx22?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab to meet a narrow requirement. It works, but my library does not support signing and encryption of the ppkg file itself. Creating a key is not the issue; my question is about algorithms/formats of the digital signature as well as format/algorithm of the encryption used by the Microsoft tool to secure the ppkg file.

Comment: Yeah wish I could help. Strange my links disappeared after just 2 months